# Самый простой способ получить bitmap с камеры на c#

Tags: c#, камера, directshow

Единственное, что нашел - это библиотека AFORGE.net с сэмплом SNAPSHOT MAKER.
Но там реализовано и потоковое видео в контрол, и снятие битмапа, в общем очень богатый функционал, который мне в корне не понадобится. Мне нужен только битмап(причем задержка между съемками более минуты), может есть более грациозное решение для получения его с камеры?

Answer (score 1):

Если не тащить громоздкие библиотеки вроде AForge.NET (которая все равно использует DirectShow API в примере из параллельного ответа), можно ограничиться библиотекой попроще [DirectShow.NET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/), в которой есть по меньшей мере два близких примера:

\DirectShowSamples-2010-February\Samples\Misc\DxWebCam

> A poor man's web cam program. This application runs as a Win32 Service.
>   It takes the output of a capture graph, turns it into a stream of JPEG 
>   files, and sends it thru TCP/IP to a client application.

\DirectShowSamples-2010-February\Samples\Capture\DxSnap

> Use DirectShow to take snapshots from the Still pin of a capture 
>   device.  Note the MS encourages you to use WIA for this, but if 
>   you want to do in with DirectShow and C#, here's how.
>
> Note that this sample will only work with devices that output uncompressed
>   video as RBG24.  This will include most webcams, but probably zero tv tuners.

В обоих случаях происходит примерно похожее: инициализация захвата видео с камеры и дальнейшая работа с кадрами (далее с видео - по вкусу: пропуск ненужного, обработка нужного).

Нужно иметь в виду следующее: у веб-камер есть нередко неприятная особенность долго начинать работу (инициализация, фокусировка и настройка баланса белого и пр.). То есть для моментального снимка нужно все время снимать и выбрасывать ненужные кадры, далее по сигналу схватить первый попавшийся (или последний имеющийся) кадр.

Comment: Очень интересно, ознакомлюсь, может лишние пару тиков сэкономит

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вот это решение [MJPEG Decoder](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder)

оно более легкое по перфе. Нет ничего лишнего. Ушел с Aforge на него.

Так же открыт исходный код для исследования.

UPD 
Либо, как советуют люди, вот так

```
        var sourceURL = "http://192.168.137.23/cgi-bin/viewer/video.jpg";
        var buffer = new byte[100000];
        int read, total = 0;
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        var resp = req.GetResponse();
        var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

        while (stream != null && (read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
            total += read;

        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));
```

sourceURL - зависит от камеры, по какому пути она отдает одиночный jpg

Comment: хм. Я может что-то не понимаю, но похоже вы говорите про IP камеру. Я же подключаю web камеру к USB. Способ то взятия картинки с урла это понятно, но мысль использовать айпи камеру и не парится не плохая.

Comment: Да. Я вел речь про IP камеры. USB камеры нету что бы пощупать :(

Answer (score 0):

Используя Aforge сделал следующим образом. (Snapshot,почему-то не срабатывало событие trigger камеры)

```
public class VideoGrabber
{
    VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    Bitmap b = null;
    public bool isRunning = false;
    public Bitmap takeSnapshot()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        b = null;

        videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);
        while (b == null)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        videoSource.NewFrame -= new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);
        isRunning = false;
        return b;

    }
    public VideoGrabber()
    {
        FilterInfoCollection videosources = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        if (videosources != null)
        {
            videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videosources[0].MonikerString);
            try
            {
                if (videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length > 0)
                {
                    string highestSolution = "0;0";
                    for (int i = 0; i < videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width > Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[0]))
                            highestSolution = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width.ToString() + ";" + i.ToString();
                    }
                    videoSource.VideoResolution = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[1])];
                }
                videoSource.Start();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        b = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (videoSource != null && videoSource.IsRunning)
        {
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            videoSource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Снимок получаю за 1-3 секунды. Хотелось бы снимок за 100-300 мс.