# Возможно ли ускорить отрисовку экрана для создания эффекта невидимости глазу, но чтобы камера успела уловить

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, aforge

**

### Изобретаем велосипед или стрельба по уткам с помощью веб камеры

**
[image: AimDuck]

Мысль о создании подобной мини игры теплилась с тех самых пор, как я впервые услышал об устройстве пистолета на денди.
Вся соль была в том, что там был лишь единственный фоторезистор, а в момент выстрела весь экран красился черным цветом, а оставшееся белое пятно и было уткой. Т.е. попадание светло, промах темно.

**Используя c#+xna затея у меня закончилась полным крахом, а именно - игрок видит метку продолжительное время. Это собственно и суть моего вопроса. Каким образом можно этого избежать? Проблема точно не в обработке фото, возможно, в получения битмапа с камеры(хотя оно занимает тоже не слишком продолжительное время), возможно в том, что между отрисовкой на экране XNA метода draw проходит тоже значительное время. Постараюсь привести исходники в более красивый вид, если, кто-то решит помочь с вопросом.**

Итак прототип прост. Меню игры, в котором не пускает дальше игры, если у пользователя нет не единой подключенной веб камеры и сама игра, где утки летяют в бесконечном цикле, если утка пролетела мимо экрана и не была подстрелена - какое-то действие(у меня <s>ржёт</s> смеется олень).

Основное размышление было над определением метки. За основу взял aforge для получения картинки с камеры т.к. на стаке мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750576/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-bitmap-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) не увенчался успехом. Сам алгоритм распознавание попадания был заложен следующий:

1. Превращение битмапа с камеры в монохромное изображение.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В определенной области от центра мы ищем белые пятна и выделяем каждое из них прямоугольниками.
3. Ищем прямоугольники внутри которых есть такой-же прямоугольник. (Тут можно было проверить расстояние от центра и закончить, т.к. данный способ давал 90% точное распознавание промахов).
4. Проверяем, что матрица цветов в прямоугольнике соответствует светло-темно-светло-темно-светло.
5. Проверяем, как далеко от центра фото - центр прямоугольника. Т.е. на сколько точно мы целимся в утку. Выдаем результат.

Логика распознавания находится в классе [CenterTest](https://github.com/SergeyToff/AimDuck/blob/master/WindowsGame2/WindowsGame2/logics/CenterTester.cs), ну и соотвествено сам проект можно взять на том же гитхабе.

[Бинарник в zip](https://github.com/SergeyToff/AimDuck/archive/0.01a.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите быстро скрыть или показать изображение, отрисовывайте его за границей экрана, а когда происходит выстрел, смещайте его на координаты центра утки. Это классический приём для геймдева.

Answer (score 0):

Проэкт интересный.

**Код я не смотрел, но кое-какие мысли имею...**

Я бы советовал в принципе брать из изображения камеры только центральный квадрат в 50х50 пикселей, например. Переводишь в ЧБ. Потом замеряешь количество белого что попадает в эту область. Этим можно значительно убыстрить обработку изображения камеры.

Вариант 2: нужно с помощью OpenCV искать на изображении темное пятно в белом. Но это, скорее всего, будет более ресурсоемким путем.

Что до медленной отрисовки...

Наверное, есть смысл попробовать отрисовывать это все не в форме, а, скажем, в юнити. Или же оптимизировать отрисовку с буфером в который ты подгружаешь кадр наперед. Показываешь его и потом сразу же возвращаешь назад.